# Read and compare properties file containing backslashes in both keys and values

Tags: java, backslash, properties-file

I am reading properties files in Java that has both keys and values that contain single or more backslashes. Examples:

```
xyz\ \ \ \ val.action.do_something\= {show} {first} &nbsp; {last} </a>

filepath=C:\folder1\folder2

i\have\backslash=the\value

i\\also\have\backslash=value
```

I know that properties.load removes backslashes from both side. How can I preserve it on both sides, even when I am comparing the values for a given key from two different properties files?

The primary intention is to compare 2 such properties files. When comparing it should compare verbatim with every character, and also should print likewise.

Comment: Maybe you should give an example of what kind of result you expect, to improve the question.

Comment: Why? The backslashes have a specific meaning that is in derstoof by `java.util.Properties.` if you're not using them for that purpose, you're doing it wrong. If you just want to compare the raw files, don't use `Properties.`

Comment: I am comparing properties files, not raw files. The files are indeed properties files. However, the properties file have entries that allow back slashes and all special characters in any sequence in both keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Putting backslash(es) in the keys is something weird and a very bad idea in my opinion. I am not sure it is allowed by properties file specifications.

Anyway, you need to escape your backslashes and other special characters (such as '=' or ':'...) so

```
filepath=C:\folder1\folder2
```

Should become

```
filepath=C\:\\folder1\\folder2
```

Have a look at [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) javadoc.

Comment: Thanks! That's understood. However, let's assume this case here. Let's say that properties file A has an entry as *this.key=a line followed by new line \n*, and properties file B has it as *this.key=a line followed by new line*. When compared, it is reporting a difference, but processing the "\n" rather than showing the characters. How can I preserve the characters when comparing or printing?

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand what you want. If you want to have a new line character in your value, you also need to escape it. Ex `my.value = Value with an new line\n` . If you want to keep the '\n' sequence, then you need to escape the backslash : `my.value = escaped new line \\n`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285551/newline-char-in-the-java-properties-file-value